# вывод указателя через указателя на объект

Tags: c++

Как вывести значение указателя p с помощью указателя на объект?

```
#include <iostream>
class Test {
    public:
        int a = 1;
        int *p = &a;
};
int main(){
    using namespace std;
    Test* obj = new Test;
    cout << obj->*p << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Так все таки "вывод указателя" или того, на что он указывает?

Comment: AnT, вывод значения "а", через указатель "p"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
class Test {
    public:
        int a = 1;
        int *p = &a;
};
int main(){
    using namespace std;
    Test* obj = new Test();
    cout << *obj->p << endl;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ага, спасибо!!!

Comment: Я сам иногда в этих указателях путаюсь

Answer (score 0):

Как-то так:

```
cout << obj->p << endl;
```

В стиле С:

```
printf("%p\n", obj->p); // насколько я помню, прошу поправить, если это не так.
```

Для получения значения (в ответ на комментарии):

```
cout << *obj->p << endl;
// некоторым может показаться понятнее такой вариант:
cout << *(obj->p) << endl;
```

Comment: @HolyBlackCat спасибо, не знал. C++ изучал по изданию книги Б. Страуструпа от 2010 года.

Comment: Я вообще новые стандарты по stackoverflow изучал. :)

Comment: cout << obj->p << endl; - так выводится адрес "a". Нужно значение "а" хранящееся в указателе, т.е. 1

Comment: @Slaine Тогда `*obj->p`.

Comment: Да, точно спасибо.

Comment: @Slaine В указателе хранится адрес, а не значение. А значение хранится как раз по этому адресу.

Comment: @VTT, так-то да, просто не правильно выразился.